# Refer to previous arguments of current command

Tags: bash

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
mv xxxx xxxx.bak
```

I know I could use this command instead:

```
mv xxxx{,.bak}
```

I think this is not direct somehow. It would be wonderful if I could do this:

```
mv xxxx $1.bak
```

And sometimes I'd need it like this:

```
echo xxxx yyyy $1.suffix
```

I know we can refer to arguments of the *previous* command using `!:n`, but can I also refer to arguments of the *current* command?

BTW, I want to do it directly in the shell, interactively.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console#165338) that uses `!$` to refer to the current command and uses `$` to refer to the previous (instead of the very first) argument. For example, `ocrmypdf --deskew --optimize 3 my.pdf !#$:r_ocr.pdf` will expand the last argument to `my_ocr.pdf`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The current command line is referenced with `!#`.

```
mv xxxx !#:1.bak
```

I recommend enabling the `histverify` option if you aren't already using it, so you have a chance to proofread or edit the results of the history expansion before actually executing it. To do so:

```
shopt -s histverify
```

Or, if you don't want to enable that option and just want to verify a single command, use the `:p` modifier to print the expansion instead of executing it:

```
$ mv xxx !#:1:p.bak
mv xxx xxx.bak
$
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use a variable for this. simply like :

```
f="file"
cp $f $f.bak
```