# Is there a way to take a previous argument?

Tags: bash

I want to do this

```
mv <some path> <some path>/../
```

Is there a way to pass `argv[1]` as my argument and manipulate it, instead of writing the whole path again?

I.e.,

```
mv <some path> argv[1]/../
```

Comment: which cli? I couldn't understand the question

Comment: Duplicate on [unix.se]: [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40128/117037), and on [su]: [How do I perform commands in another folder, without repeating the folder path?](https://superuser.com/q/596712/443564)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23244081/4518341).
You can do it with:

```
mv file.txt !#:1.backup
```

- `!#` - refers to the current command.
- `!#:1` - refers to the first argument of the current command

If you run this example you'll get:

```
mv file.txt file.txt.backup
```

Comment: Notice that history expansion (which this is a part of) is disabled for non-interactive shells by default, so this wouldn't work in a script without explicitly enabling it first.

Answer (score 2):

In these situations, I usually use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
mv <some path>{,/../}
```

which will expand to

```
mv <some path> <some path>/../
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo mv some/path{,/../other/path}
mv some/path some/path/../other/path
```

---

As @Pavlo Myroniuk points out in his answer, you can also follow the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23244081/276052) and do:

```
mv <some path> !#:1/../
```